# Nullability (Regular Expressions)

Tags: regex, nullable, derivative

In Brzozowski's "Derivatives of Regular Expressions" and elsewhere, the function δ(R) returning λ if a R is nullable, and ∅ otherwise, includes clauses such as the following:

```
δ(R1 + R2) = δ(R1) + δ(R2)
δ(R1 · R2) = δ(R1) ∧ δ(R2)
```

Clearly, if both *R1* and *R2* are nullable then (*R1 · R2*) is nullable, and if either *R1* or *R2* is nullable then (*R1 + R2*) is nullable. It is unclear to me what the above clauses are supposed to mean, however. My first thought, mapping  (+), (·), or the Boolean operations to regular sets is nonsensical, since in the base case,

```
δ(a) = ∅ (for all a ∈ Σ)
δ(λ) = λ
δ(∅) = ∅
```

and λ is not a set (nor is a set the return type of δ, which is a regular expression). Furthermore, this mapping isn't indicated, and there is a separate notation for it. I understand nullability, but I'm lost on the definition of the sum, product, and Boolean operations in the definition of δ: how are λ or ∅ returned from δ(*R1*) ∧ δ(*R2*), for instance, in the definition off δ(*R1 · R2*)?

Comment: This should be on Theoretical CS instead: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I was under the impression that *cstheory.stackexchange* is intended for research-level questions. If so, this question is certainly *not* appropriate for the site. There are many questions of this level about regular expressions on this site.

Comment: I'm pretty comfortable with nearly everything on SO, but this question confuses me to no end. I think you'll get more eyes at cstheory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're getting caught out by the notational liberties taken by the author. The return type of δ(R) is most certainly a set, or rather a language. If you look at the definition:

[image]

you can see that there is an inconsistency in the return type, formally λ is an element, but ∅ is the empty language... What it should say is:

[image]

The fact that the author uses λ for both the empty string as well as the language containing only the empty string is further evidenced by his definition of the Kleene star operator:

[image]

Clearly, the last part should be [image] if we want to be pedantic.

Given that the return type of δ(R) is a set, or rather a language, the equations you give make perfect sense and express exactly what you described.

Comment: I believe you're correct. I'm accustomed to seeing L(R) (or any equivalent notation, such as [R]) for the language of a regular expression. It remains odd that the author uses δ in the definition of derivatives to denote a regular expression. If δ denoted a regular expression, and not a language ({λ} or ∅), either of the regular expressions λ or ∅ are obtained in the recursive cases of δ by simple algebra (for instance, ∅ + λ = λ).

Answer (score 3):

I think you were right to map `+` and `^` to boolean `or` and `and` respectively. It looks like the two lines you cited deal with *alternation* (sum) and *concatenation* (product):

```
δ(R1 + R2) = δ(R1) + δ(R2)
```

The *alternation* of `R1` and `R2` is nullable if `R1` is nullable, `R2`is nullable, or both `R1` and `R2` are nullable.

```
δ(R1 · R2) = δ(R1) ∧ δ(R2)
```

The *concatenation* of `R1` and `R2` is only nullable if both `R1` and `R2` are nullable.

See [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Regular_expressions_for_XML_Schema#The_idea_of_derivations_of_regular_expressions) for an Haskell implementation of these rules.

Comment: Hmm - If I were defining a function *nullable*, suitable clauses would be *nullable(R1 + R2) = nullable(R1) ∨ nullable(R2)* (as you said, the sum of R1 and R2 is nullable if the disjunction of nullable(R1) and nullable(R2) is true) and *nullable(R1 · R2) = nullable(R1) ∧ nullable(R2)*. So I could clearly define the function δ as *δ(R) = case nullable(R) of True -> λ; False -> ∅*. While it's correct, it's not the point, I think, since the return value of the function is λ or the empty language, and it isn't employing a mechanism like "case."

Answer (score 2):

(I can't look into the article by Brzozowski in order to understand better what is meant there), but I can suggest 2 ways to interprete this notation (apart from gettingalong with the notation, I see, there is no question: the intended sense of this definition is well understood):

1) On left of the definition, we have just "syntactic" patterns for the regular expressions. On the right, we produce sets; remember, that a regular expression is a way to denote a language (a set), and so this way to write down the definition becomes understandable: on the right, we simply use some (simple) regular expressions as a short way to refer to sets. I.e.,∅ means the empty language (the empty set), and λ (if *interpreted* as a regular expression) means the language containing just the empty word (the set with this element).

The operations are simply operations on sets: probably union, and intersection.

If the notation is interpreted this way, there is no contradiction with the used notation to defian the base case: again, "a" is a regular expression which stands there to mean the language with the word "a".

2) We build regular expressons on the right, in the first place, but the author has extended the operations which build regular expressions with the wedge, which has the semantics of intersection of languages.